# saving depth image into pcd

Tags: ros, kinect, pcl, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to save the depth images into pcd format files which I viewed in rviz through openni_kinect. Can someone gives some clues?
Thanks

Best,
Kang

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10007/saving-depth-image-into-pcd/) by [kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/468/kang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2011-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Kang,

There is a PCL tutorial on writing point cloud data to PCD files available [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/writing_pcd.php#writing-pcd). Additionally, there is a simple tool called pointcloud_to_pcd which does this and is located in the pcl_ros folder. You would run something along the lines of:

```
rosrun pcl_ros pointcloud_to_pcd input:=/camera/depth/points2
```

if your depth data was being published on /camera/depth/points2. The node would then write a PCD file for each message it received.

Hope this helps,

Peter

---

Originally posted by [pbrook](https://answers.ros.org/users/226/pbrook/) with karma: 226 on 2011-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/468/kang/) on 2011-05-20**:
Thanks Peter, I did not notice that we should mention the input. Now, it works.